# Will I be able to take a Norway - Netherlands - Norway flight with only a Norwegian drivers license?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, schengen, passports, netherlands

I am in the middle of a work trip. I started off in Stavanger (Norway), and flew to Oslo (Norway) where I am at a conference for a day. Tomorrow, I am supposed to fly from Oslo Gardermoen airport to Amsterdam Schiphol airport. Then a day after, I will be returning to Stavanger.

Halfway through today I realized that I have forgotten my passport in Stavanger, and the only form of ID I have on me is a Norwegian driver's license. Returning to Stavanger to pick it up is not an option for me.

Will I be able to travel to Amsterdam and then back to Norway with the ID I have on me? It *seems* that I should not have a problem entering or leaving the Netherlands, because of Schengen regulations. Based on previous experience, I am fairly certain that I will not need to show an ID of any sort in Oslo either. But, is there some sort of ID check in Schiphol where they might not like the ID I have on me? When I go through airport security, will they also ask to see my passport? (I know some airports do this, for example and off the top of my head, JFK).

If it helps, I am a EU citizen, I have no checked-in luggage (only carry on), I do all my check-ins on my phone (so no contact with airline employees), and my flights to and from Schiphol should go from terminal B, which seems to be the Schengen one. The airlines are SAS on the way there, and KLM on the way back.

My current plan is to show up at the airport and see how it goes. Worst case scenario, I am not allowed on the plane, or I have to stay an extra few days in AMS while I have my passport sent to me (not the end of the world). But I would like to know in advance if I should have a reasonable expectation that I will be asked for ID at some point.

Thank you for any information you can share!

Comment: The requirement is some form of proof of citizenship, which a drivers lincense does not fulfill. Any chance on getting a scan of your passport page? That may help if a more thorough check is done.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I do thankfully have a scan of it. I suppose in a pinch they should be able to look it up?

Comment: Even though there should not be any systematic checks between Schengen countries (I.e. you are unlikely to go through a regular passport/visa control desk), spot checks can happen anywhere, and you should be able to prove your citizenship, which your driver’s license will not. Also, there can be ID checks at check-in (doesn’t apply to you), security (never seen any) or at the boarding gate, though policies for that (whether they happen and what documents are acceptable) vary a lot based on country, airline, destination… I have no experience on those specific routes.

Comment: Your problem here is the airline.  They will be stricter than any border guards who might check you.  Have you asked the airline what documents they will accept?

Comment: @jcaron indeed, that is more or less what I thought the case would be. There is a high chance that I do not have to show any ID, except for a random check or the airline deciding to check when boarding the plane. I am trying to think if I've ever had to show ID in Schiphol before, but I've only ever been through in transit, never *starting* a trip there.

Comment: @phoog good question, I have not. I suppose a call to customer service cannot hurt.

Comment: The SAS website has info on the topic: https://www.flysas.com/en/travel-info/passport-id-visa/entry-regulations/#europe

Comment: There might be a way to get temporary/emergency travel documents at the airport. (E.g. in Germany, as a German, you'd go to the federal police station at the airport.)

Comment: @jcaron thank you for sharing that link! This does give me some peace if mind, as it seems that chances of being asked for identification are low. I do wonder now what the penalty would be for not being able to produce a document. But of course, that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @user24582 I hold a Spanish passport. I wonder how this would work if I find myself in the Netherlands in need of a passport? I suppose I would need to work that out with the embassy. At that point, it might be faster to FedEx the passport itself from Norway to the NL...

Comment: @EugeneRomero, I would have that passport send to the Netherlands. It is rather likely that if the airline does not want you boarding with only a driving license you are stuck in the Netherlands.

Comment: @Willeke yes, that is a good point. I am only in the Netherlands for a day, so I think I will risk it. If I end up stuck there, I can stay a few extra nights while the passport is sent over. Otherwise, I don't end up risking my passport ending up in the Netherlands without me there 

Comment: What is the practice in the Netherlands when it comes to having to show an id when checking in to a hotel? Planning to stay a few days if you are not allowed to go back to Norway may not be so funny if you can't get a place to stay.

Comment: @Willeke how is he going to get to the Netherlands?  SAS says (at the page linked by charon) "However, you still need to carry a national identity card or passport to verify your citizenship if required."  I doubt SAS would board a passenger with only a driver's license.  Maybe KLM is different, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @phoog, If he is not able to leave Norway, he is in the same country as his passport, which takes away the risk for being stuck in an other country. If he is able to get his first flight but not the return one, that is where getting the passport send is very important.

Comment: @phoog My experience is that SAS rarely checks any id when I am flying from Oslo to other Schengen countries. They are not obligated to do so. You can check in online, the bag drop is unstaffed and at the gate, it is sufficient to show a boarding pass.

Comment: @phoog as described earlier, while in some circumstances there are ID checks at the gate (e.g. in France — Air France tried stopping those checks a few years back but they were forced to reintroduce them a few months later), in others (based on the airline and country), there are no ID checks at the gate at all (at least for intra-Schengen flights). Yo just need a boarding pass. You are **supposed** to have relevant ID and/or visa, but airlines are actually not allowed to check those for intra-Schengen, they are only allowed “security” checks.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I have  now successfully returned from this trip and have described how it went for me in an answer below. Also, adding to @Tor-EinarJarnbjo 's question: I was not asked for any form of ID when checking into my hotel in Amsterdam.

Comment: And for @phoog , SAS never checked IDs at the gate in any of the flights, thankfully. I would probably would have been turned away otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of control, a Passport or ID card will be needed to prove your identity.

> Even if you don't need a passport for border checks within the Schengen area , it is still always highly recommended to take a passport or ID card with you, so you can prove your identity if needed (if stopped by police, boarding a plane, etc.

and

> Driving licences, post, bank or tax cards are not accepted as valid travel documents or proof of identity.

Source: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have added my own answer describing how the situation played out for me. However, your answer describes the *legal* aspect of the issue, and therefore I will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 6):

So, after successfully having returned to Norway, I can answer my own question.

**Is it *possible* to successfully perform this trip?**: Yes

**Is it *legal* to perform this trip?**: Not really, as per the law you should always carry proof of citizenship.

**Will anyone ask to look at ID during the trip?**: Probably not. You will never cross any official passport checks, so the only things left would be some sort of a random spot check (I have never seen this happen) or a check at the gate (airline employee checking IDs as the flight is boarded - this happens randomly, and it is up to the airline employee to decide if to allow you on board or not if he is not satisfied).

I did not face any gate checks, and managed to do Oslo-Copenhagen, Copenhagen-Amsterdam (my original Oslo-Amsterdam flight was cancelled), and Amsterdam-Stavanger without ever being asked for ID. But for example, the flight before mine at the gate in Oslo, which was to Helsinki (Finland), was checking IDs, and a passenger was actually unable to board his flight because of some possible issue with whatever document he presented.

So in the end, I do not recommend attempting this. It will probably work in a pinch, but per the law, always carry proof of citizenship on you.